# FluentAssertions: comparing shared properties of list members

Tags: fluent-assertions

I have to compare two collections taking into account only the shared properties.
If I understand Dennis' comment on [How to combine collection and property assertions using fluent-assertions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006820/fluentassertions-combining-collection-and-property-assertions) this should work as of version 2.0.

I am using this API:

```
ActualOes.ShouldHave().SharedProperties().EqualTo(expectedOes);
```

ActualOes is of type `IEnumerable<IOe>` and expectedOes is `IEnumerable<Object>` where the elements are objects of an anonymous type sharing just a few properties with the actual `IOe` interface.

When I run this, FA complains about the missing properties.

Am I using the wrong API?

Comment: Updated to make the generics show up correctly in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work like that, although since FA 2.0 that API is not the recommended way of doing this (although that old API is using the new API under the hood). I need to see if any of the unit tests is covering this particular scenario.

Comment: What would be the recommended way of doing this?